# Using iconv command in bash - incomplete character or shift sequence error

Tags: bash, macos, unix, iconv

I am trying to convert a `.csv` from UTF-16LE to UTF-8. The file is too large to be opened in Excel, and I am encountering the "incomplete character or shift sequence" error when using the following command:

```sh
iconv -f utf-16le -t -c utf-8 myfilename.csv > mynewfilename.csv
```

How do I get past this?

I'm using Bash on Mac OS Mojave.

Thanks!

---

Edit to add:

```
iconv -c -f utf-16le -t utf-8//IGNORE myfilename.csv > mynewfilename.csv
```

also didn't work, per suggestion below.

Comment: 1) Move `-c` option as the first parameter.  2) Use `utf-8//IGNORE` as the output conversion

Comment: BTW, iconv is an external command, not part of bash; it can be run from any shell, or with no shell at all. I'd consider `unix` as a more appropriate tag for things that aren't actually bash-specific.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Sadly

'''iconv -c -f utf-16le -t utf-8//IGNORE my filename.csv.csv > mynewfilename.csv'''

gave me the same "incomplete character or shift sequence" error.

Comment: Try a binary search for whatever is causing the problem... take the first half of your file with `head -c NNN > tmp` and feed that into `iconv` then either take 1/4 or 3/4 till you can isolate the issue. If you do get an error, you need to try `head -c NNN+1` to be sure the bisection wasn't responsible for causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I tested a file with and without BOM.

Removing the BOM before using `iconv` works without any error.